# Do we know why Harry was made a godfather?

Tags: harry-potter

About two thirds of the way in to *Deathly Hallows*, Harry gets made in to a godfather. Do we know anything, whether that be from the books, interviews, or any other official source, about why the parents gave him this role? I can't think of any aspects of his personality that would make him well-suited for the task, and the way things were going, he was likely to die soon anyway.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I can't think of any aspects of his personality that would make him
> well-suited for the task

Really? Because Lupin probably can. Remember, Lupin was fully ready to abandon his own kid until Harry set him straight. Harry actually turned away Lupin's help when the fate of the world was at stake, saying that parents should protect their kids. He called his former mentor and friend a selfish coward to his face. Harry showed a more paternal attitude towards Teddy than the boy's actual father, prized his welfare above the greater good, and was willing to place a close friendship in jeopardy to do what was right for him.

From Lupin's perspective, Harry was an excellent choice. I don't disagree.

I'll leave you with Lupin's own estimation of Harry:

> "'The Boy Who Lived' remains a symbol of everything for which we are
> fighting: the triumph of good, the power of innocence, the need to
> keep resisting."
>
> A mixture of gratitude and shame welled up in Harry. Had Lupin
> forgiven him, then, for the terrible things he had said when they had
> last met?
>
> "And what would you say to Harry if you knew he was listening,
> Romulus?"
>
> "I'd tell him we're all with him in spirit," said Lupin, then
> hesitated slightly, "And I'd tell him to follow his instincts, which
> are good and nearly always right." *(DH, "The Deathly Hallows")*